# Code to check for when a value in a column changes

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a macro that will look at a column and if it sees the value change then it inserts a new row. I've worked some code below but I'm jus getting Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Sub FormatMyData()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim Value As String

    Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, D).Value
    Col = "D"
    StartRow = 1
    BlankRows = 1


    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, Col) <> Value Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                 Value = Cells(R + 2, Col)
        End If

        Next R
    End With


End Sub
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ok I though I had found the error but apparently not still need help

Answer (score 0):

You should also say where exactly the Error occurs, so we have an easier job to help you.

The things I found were the following:

- use `Sheets` instead of `Worksheets`
- in the line you read out the `Value` use .Cells(2, **"D"**).Value
- in your loop on changing your `Value` you´re using Cells without specifiing the `Sheet`
- since you´re using a `With` on the Sheet, you can spare some code

so change your code like this:

```
Sub FormatMyData()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim Value As String

    Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "D").Value
    Col = "D"
    StartRow = 1
    BlankRows = 1


    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(R, Col) <> Value Then
                .Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                 Value = .Cells(R + 2, Col)
            End If

        Next R
    End With


End Sub
```